# How to count the number of words of each sentences in a file using shell command?

Tags: shell-script, sed, awk, grep, wc

I have text files like this:

```
Mr.P.K.Baneerjee has visited the site today at 4.30pm
The permit tag has been set in the ds busbar
Opearation has been performed in presence of control engineer
Opeation was successfully completed
```

All files have only four lines

Only the count of words must be printed as an output, just like this:

```
8
10
9
4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with:

`awk '{print NF}' filename`

Comment: FTR, NF (number of fields) works because awk uses space as field separator (FS) by default.

Answer (score 3):

Since you tagged your question with `wc`, here's a solution (albeit non-optimal) that uses it:

```
while read -r line; do echo $line | wc -w; done < filename.txt
```